# jersey 2 library response.getEntity not exist what should I use instead

Tags: netbeans

my code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package beans;

import clients.NewJerseyClient;



import entities.ReservationItem;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;

import parameters.ReservationParam;
import  org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author subhi2
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PageController implements Serializable {

    public String moveToPage2() {

        NewJerseyClient client = new NewJerseyClient();

        ClientResponse response = client.findInsertedReservationItem(ClientResponse.class, "22", "2010-07-26T11:15:51", "2014-07-26T11:15:51");


        GenericType<List<ReservationItem>> genericType = new GenericType<List<ReservationItem>>() {
        };
// Returns an ArrayList of Players from the web service
        List<ReservationItem> data = new ArrayList<ReservationItem>();



        data = (response.getEntity(genericType));
        return data.toString();
    }
}
```

the line 
data = (response.getEntity(genericType));
cause the error

this code was working with old jersey but now what should I do to solve this error ?

Answer (score 4):

You can change response.getEntity(genericType) by response.readEntity(genericType)

Answer (score 2):

For what you are asking I've replaced this

```
response.getEntity(String.class);
```

by this

```
response.getEntityStream().toString();
```

But there could be another problems related with Jersey 2, I could get it working by replacing these imports

```
import jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
```

By these

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
```

and in the code (as I was using Jetty) I had to replace  this

```
servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", 
                               "resources");
```

by this

```
servletHolder.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", 
                               "resources");
```

and this

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://url_u_want_to_connect");
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
```

by this

```
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://url_u_want_to_connect");
ClientResponse response = webTarget.request("application/json")
```

---

Finally here is a link for "latest" docs (It's about Jersey 2.x, at 2013)

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html

Comment: I have just encountered the same issue. Thank you for the reply, however I do not like this change as `response.getEntity(String.class)` looks a lot more cleaner than `response.getEntityStream().toString();`

Comment: response.getEntityStream is not present in jersey 2.7. response.readEntity(genericType) is present as mentioned by @amgohan